# substring replace nth positions R

Tags: r

I need to replace the 6,7,8th position to "_". In substring, I mentioned the start and stop position. It didn't work.

```
> a=c("UHI786KJRH2V", "TYR324FHASJKDG","DHA927NFSYFN34")
> substring(a, 6,8) <- "_"
> a
[1] "UHI78_KJRH2V"   "TYR32_FHASJKDG" "DHA92_NFSYFN34"
```

I need `UHI78_RH2V  TYR32_ASJKDG  DHA92_SYFN34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`, we can match on the pattern `(?<=^.{5}).{3}`, and then replace it by a single underscore:

```
a <- c("UHI786KJRH2V", "TYR324FHASJKDG","DHA927NFSYFN34")
out <- sub("(?<=^.{5}).{3}", "_", a, perl=TRUE)
out
[1] "UHI78_RH2V"   "TYR32_ASJKDG" "DHA92_SYFN34"
```

### Demo

We could also try doing substring operations here, but we would have to do some splicing:

```
out <- paste0(substr(a, 1, 5), "_", substr(a, 9, nchar(a)))
```

Comment: Can avoid `nchar()` with: `paste0(substr(a, 1, 5), "_", substring(a, 9))`

Answer (score 1):

**1) str_sub<-** The `str_sub<-` replacement function in the stringr package can do that.

```
library(stringr)

str_sub(a, 6, 8) <- "_"
a
## [1] "UHI78_RH2V"   "TYR32_ASJKDG" "DHA92_SYFN34"
```

**2 Base R** With only base R you could do this.  It replaces the entire string with the match to the first capture group, an underscore and the match to the second capture group.

```
sub("(.....)...(.*)", "\\1_\\2", a)
## [1] "UHI78_RH2V"   "TYR32_ASJKDG" "DHA92_SYFN34"
```

That regex could also be written as `"(.{5}).{3}(.*)"` .

**3) separate/unite**  If `a` is a column in a data frame then we could use dplyr and tidyr to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF <- data.frame(a)

DF %>% 
  separate(a, into = c("pre", "junk", "post"), sep = c(5, 8)) %>%
  select(-junk) %>% 
  unite(a)
```

giving:

```
             a
1   UHI78_RH2V
2 TYR32_ASJKDG
3 DHA92_SYFN34
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If the portion to be replaced is longer than the replacement string, then only the portion the length of the string is replaced.

So we could do something like this:

```
substring(a, 6,8) <- "_@@"
sub("@+", "", a)
[1] "UHI78_RH2V"   "TYR32_ASJKDG" "DHA92_SYFN34"
```